# Python/Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am fairly new to Python/Django.
What I would like to do is to store descriptions of cars separately, but simultaneously I would like to label (in django admin) car description like this:

```
class CarDescription(models.Model):

    length = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "description of the car no %d" % (Car.id)


class Car(models.Model):

    description = models.OneToOneField(CarDescription)
```

I know that Car.id is wrong there (circular reference). Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Why would you want to store it separately, if there is 1-to-1 relationship? It will make your life harder with no benefits.

Comment: Well, I would like to split it, because it can have potentially many fields. I would prefer to have two entities with smaller amount of attributes rather than one with many attributes.

Comment: what is your reasoning behind it? You have to have real good reasons for such insane normalization.

Comment: ok, if you want it THAT much, just add string field to CarDescription and that's it. But seriously, I doubt it is reasonable.

Comment: Ok, so you suggest to split class only in case of some kind of inheritance? And generally not to introduce one-to-one relation?

Comment: @JosephConrad well, I made a mistake so I'm going to delete my previous comment, I thought you used a `ForeignKey` In this case, since it is one-to-one, there shouldn't be much need as Andrey said. BUT if you were to do so, you would access it via `self.car.id`

Comment: @JosephConrad Yes, if it is a true 1-to-1 relation just include the description in your Car model. If you have a bunch of additional fields you are not posting, then these can be avoided using [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should structure your models like this:

```
class Car(models.Model):

    # everything that has to do _only_ with a car

class CarDescription(models.Model):

    car = models.ForeignKey(Car) # each description can belong to only one car
    length = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    # other fields that have only to do with a description

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode("description of the car no %d" % (self.car.pk))
```

Django has a very nice API for looking up [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) which you should go through (once you have finished the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)).

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
class Car(models.Model):

    description = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Done. More fields are fine. You're overcomplicating things otherwise.

You need to study what's called "relational modeling".

What you're doing is "premature optimization" and probably "pessimization".

Answer (score 0):

You can check django's document, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#one-to-one-relationships.

As addressed in the doc, you can access one to one fields directly,

```
class CarDescription(models.Model):

    length = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "description of the car no %d" % (self.car.id)
```

It works only both car and car description instances exists, or else exception will be thrown.